# No overload matches this call (for a simple array from an api)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

i got the error above when I was trying to use a .map function for an simple array (['a','b','c']) and  I got the array from using useEffect hook. No error on console and the array elements rendered perfectly fine when I run the code. The error is only on typescript so I wish to make it got away.Error was flagged at the {category}

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Xna.png)

Comment: You cannot directly render an object with JSX. Did you mean `{category.name}`?

Comment: Hi, this is the array and I don't think I can do category.name [
    "smartphones",
    "laptops",
    "fragrances",
    "skincare",
    "groceries",
    "home-decoration",
    "furniture",
    "tops",
    "womens-dresses",
    "womens-shoes",
    "mens-shirts",
    "mens-shoes",
    "mens-watches",
    "womens-watches",
    "womens-bags",
    "womens-jewellery",
    "sunglasses",
    "automotive",
    "motorcycle",
    "lighting"
]

Comment: That does not match your type definition for `Category`

Comment: Please, dont paste code as an image, just copy in the editor and mark it as code and it will format it automatically, aldo it will help others to reproduce the code

Answer (score 0):

Your type definition for `Category` is...

> ```ts
> interface Category {
>   name: string;
> }
> ```

Typescript is expecting your state to be an array of such objects. JSX cannot directly render objects, hence your error.

If the API response is actually an array of plain strings, you should either transform it to match your interface...

```ts
setCategories(response.data.map((name) => ({ name })));
```

and display the appropriate property

```tsx
<List>
  {categories.map(({ name }, index) => (
    <ListItem key={index}>{name}</ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
```

or simply define `Category` as plain string

```ts
type Category = string;
```

```tsx
<List>
  {categories.map((category, index) => (
    <ListItem key={index}>{category}</ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
```